# OS X New Notifications

Tags: c#, macos, cocoa

Is there a way to check if there are new Notifications in the Notification Center?
I mean, messages not seen by the user.

I don't want to read the content, but only if there are fresh notification in it.

I checked support docs, but I guess due to the sandbox, apps have no access to the item count of new notes in the notifications center.

Comment: You app can check the number of notifications for your app, you can't ask about other apps.

Comment: even not ouzside the sandbox mode ?

Comment: the NSUserNotificationCenter is a per-application object and only provides access to notifications intended for the current application bundle. There is no API for determining this information. You could try reading the DB in `/Users/<user>/Library/Application Support/NotificationCenter`, which is the internal representation of the state of the notification center.